# Why can't I use \edef with \pageref from hyperref?

Tags: hyperref

This works nicely:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \label{mylabel}
    \pageref{mylabel}
    \edef\mypage{\pageref{mylabel}}
\end{document}
```

But using `hyperref`, thus replacing `\pageref` by `\pageref*` to have only the page number without the link, this does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \label{mylabel}
    \pageref*{mylabel}
    \edef\mypage{\pageref*{mylabel}}
\end{document}
```

The error is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6     \edef\mypage
                 {\pageref*{mylabel}}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.
```

Why is that, and how can I do it better?

Comment: Adding `\def\mypage\relax` before `\edef`fixes the error, but then `\mypage` after `\edef` raises `Use of \mypage doesn't match its definition. \end`

Comment: if you put `\def\mypage\relax` there then the full definition is `\def\mypage\relax\edef\mypage{\pageref*{mylabel}}` and `\mypage` is defined such that it has to be followed by `\relax\edef\mypage` and expands to `\pageref*{mylabel}` (which would generate an error that the generated expand is not followed by `\relax`  the `{}` are _mandatory_ in `\def` so it includes all the tokens up the the `{}` it finds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commands taking a *-variant are not expandable, so they can't be used in `\edef`.

The particular error is not really meaningful; if you go past it and try running LaTeX again, you get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\HyRef@StarSetRef ...Hy@safe@activestrue \edef \x
```

You get what you'd like with `refcount` and `\getpagerefnumber`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\label{mylabel}
\pageref*{mylabel}
\edef\mypage{\getpagerefnumber{mylabel}}

\mypage

\end{document}
```

The output shows 1 twice as expected.

Using `\protected@edef` as suggested in another answer is not what you're looking for. Here's an extended example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\label{mylabel}
\pageref*{mylabel}
\edef\mypage{\getpagerefnumber{mylabel}}

\mypage

\makeatletter
\protected@edef\mypageagain{\pageref*{mylabel}}
\makeatother

\texttt{\meaning\mypage}

\texttt{\meaning\mypageagain}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see that `\mypageagain` doesn't contain the page number.

Comment: Yes, that works!

Comment: Also, `\refused{mylabel}` should be added to get a warning, if `mylabel` is still undefined. Since a warning will not work in an expandable context like by `\edef`, it cannot be included in the expandable `\getpagerefnumber`.

Answer (score 6):

You can not, in general, use `\edef` on general latex text, the fact that you do not get an error in the first use is purely by chance. More or less any `*` command is going to fail as `\@ifnextchar` does not work by expansion so it will fail in the lookahead for the `*` irrespective of the command definition.

This is the origin of the "fragile command" distinction in LaTeX and why latex commands should use `\protected@edef` so `\protect` is set up to make fragile commands safe before the edef.  (But being safe means it may not expand as you need, you did not give your actual use case here)

Comment: Thanks! Basically, I want to compare whether two labels are on the same page, so I thought about storing the expanded `\pageref`s in two macros and comparing those...

Comment: @bers you can use `ifthenelse` which locally makes pageref safe while testing (but I wouldn't) or use Heiko's zref suite which is designed for this

Comment: Yes, thanks for that suggestion. I was actually trying to do the same without an extra package (thus, without `ifthenelse`), so now I just need to choose between that and `refcount`. The latter is easier because it works the same way with and without `hyperref`; in the former, I need an additional check for `hyperref`.

Comment: @bers I don't trust the author of `ifthen` I wouldn't use it personally.